# How do I setup PyCharm as an IDE for Autodesk Maya on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pycharm, maya

I have Maya 2014 (64-bit) and Pycharm 3.0 How can I setup Pycharm in such a way that I can use it for Maya. This feature was implemented in Pycharm 3.0 as you can see. [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/PyCharm+3.0+Roadmap) I am using Linux

Comment: Detailed instructions here:  http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?3153-Setting-up-PyCharm-for-use-with-Maya-2013&highlight=pycharm

Comment: can you confirm which distro you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference maya commands in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072433/how-to-reference-maya-commands-in-pycharm)