# How to reference maya commands in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, maya

I am trying to get pycharm (latest community edition) working with maya 2015.
And the very first thing I need is to be able to reference maya commands module, but I don't seem to be able to find how.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
```

fails with

```
ImportError: No module named maya.cmds
```

What do I need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 9):

I'm on Mac, but the steps should be the same on Windows, only some paths will differ.

#### Setup the Maya Python interpreter in Pycharm

1. In Pycharm, open your preferences and find *Project Interpreter*.
2. Next to the drop-down list, click the little [...] icon, and choose *Add Local*.
3. Locate *mayapy.exe* or *mayapy* depending on your system. This is found in the *bin* folder in your Maya installation directory. On Mac it's located under `.../Autodesk/maya2016.5/Maya.app/Contents/bin/mayapy`

#### To make completions work

1. Download the Maya developer kit (Google will help you) and extract it to a meaningful location.
2. Click the [...] next to the drop-down list again and select *More...*.
3. Select your newly added interpreter from the steps above, it will be named
   something like `Python 2.7.6 (/path/to/mayapy)`
4. Click the *Paths* button in the bottom toolbar 
   [image: Pycharm Interpreter Toolbar]
5. Click the + sign and locate the folder where you extracted the developer kit. Then navigate to `.../devkit/other/pymel/extras/extras/completion/py/` and hit OK.

You should have a working setup with completion.

Based on information from [this forum topic](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?3153-Setting-up-PyCharm-for-use-with-Maya-2013).

Edit:
If you find it is still not working, ensure you go back into the paths for the interpreter (outlined above), look for, and select, a path called `.../Python/Lib/site-packages` and remove this file (press the **-** button).
This information is also outlined in the above forum link.

Comment: What would be the steps to create a platform neutral interpreter? I'm developing cross-platform tools, so I'm wondering if using mayapy.exe is going to mess up code for another software such as Houdini. Would using the system's default python.exe be possible?

Comment: I believe you can use any python interpreter. Just keep in mind that Maya uses version 2.7.6 - see this page https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-C0F27A50-3DD6-454C-A4D1-9E3C44B3C990-htm.html. Also, you can setup different interpreters based on your pycharm project. So one for houdini, another for maya.