# Is it possible to develop across multiple software packages (Maya, Houdin, Nuke, etc) from a single master interpreter?

Tags: python, maya, interpreter, nuke, houdini

I'm developing universal tools that work across various CG software packages such as Maya, Houdini, Nuke, etc., and **I'm wondering if there's a workflow for merging each software's custom interpreter into a single master interpreter inside a virtual environment?**

To elaborate:

[I know how create a custom environment for Maya development in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072433/how-to-reference-maya-commands-in-pycharm), but this only works with `mayapy.exe` as the interpreter. I'd ideally like to use a clean `python.exe` as my master interpreter, then add packages for each software in order to get completion working.

[Here's a gist of the script I've been working with.](https://gist.github.com/mikebourbeauart/8689e511ce7f5fa1f75db5f39890d058) All it needs is `PySide` and `Qt.py` installed into a `Python 2.7 venv` to run. If I do all the steps from the first link (Maya dev in PyCharm) EXCEPT use `mayapy.exe` as the interpreter and instead use `python.exe` I've found that autocompletion actually works, but the script will not execute unless I'm using the `mayaypy.exe` as the interpreter.

**I guess my main problem is I'm not sure if this is even possible.** And if it is possible I'm not sure what packages to use or how to find out what packages I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to make some mocking (see mock module) or use external interpreters of each application.

You can also clone to your main python site-packages the application's commands in order to have the auto-completation.
If I remember nuke has already a clone for autocompletion but maya is more tricky.

---EDIT---
I remember only for nuke and maya (the ressources for maya is old but might be helpful)

For nuke :

http://www.nukepedia.com/written-tutorials/using-eclipse-with-nuke
http://www.nukepedia.com/python/misc/nukepydummy
https://help.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/content/comp_environment/configuring_nuke/command_line_operations.html

For maya :

https://www.highend3d.com/maya/downloads/applications/syntax-scripting/c/eclipse-autocompletion-for-maya-python-api
https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/eclipse.html
http://www.toadstorm.com/blog/?p=136

Comment: Seems to be a good idea. So mocking will allow my code to run, but in order to get auto complete in the IDE I need to clone python commands from Houdini, Maya, Nuke, etc. into my venv's site package? Any resources for this?

Comment: It has been a long time I didn't have investigated this (all major companies has already something like this). I remember, I've found these ressources looking to setup Eclypse (I've edited my answer with what I could remember)

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I'll see what I can do with this.